# How to brand a web page based on the host in the request?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4

Ok, so I am building a page that will ultimately be branded based on the request host. For instance, if a user browses to www.firsthost.com, my filter will detect this and set it to brand 1. If the user browses to www.secondhost.com, my filter detects it and sets it brand 2. These brand ids are used to dynamically select assets and options on the page.

Currently, what I'm doing is making this determination inside of an ActionFilter and stuffing the brand id into the session and then referencing it at the controller, which I use to build a view model with the correct references and assets. What I don't like about this is that I have to create a method that digs this brand id out of the session and call it with every action in the controller, and I really don't like the idea of stuffing it into the session either. Obviously I'm going to want to hide this from the user, so I don't really want to put it into a cookie.

Has anyone approached this before? How did you solve this? I'm just looking for a cleaner if not safer way to achieve this functionality, and if the framework already has something to aid with this, I'd prefer to use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in a filter and pass the brand information to the view in the ViewBag. Something like this would conceptually work:

```
public class SetBrandFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.Brand = GetBrandInformationForHost(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host)
    }
}
```

You could make this filter into an attribute and apply it to your controllers (or to a base controller), or register it as a global filter. You would handle all of the brand data inside this filter, so you wouldn't have to worry about it in your actions at all.

This is similar to what you're doing now, but instead of using the session (which isn't really necessary for the type of data you are passing around, since it only relates to a single request) you use the ViewBag.

Comment: You know what, I didn't even notice that I had a controller reference in there. I tested it as working. Let me play around with it a bit more and make sure it's solid. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :) You should be able to load all of the brand data inside the filter and completely ignore brands in your actions. The brand data on the ViewBag will get sent directly to the view.

Comment: Oooh, I'm not sure I'd wanna do that. No use loading brand specific assets for all of the pages. While it work for most things, some pages may have significantly more to display than others and I don't wanna be loading those up every time the filter gets hit. As it is, those view models get created as needed.

Comment: Then, like I mentioned in the answer, you can make this into an Attribute and only apply it to the actions or controllers you need, rather than across the board. The main point though, is that inside the actions themselves you shouldn't have to do anything related to loading the brand data. You've extracted that cross-cutting concern into a re-usable package that can be applied as needed.

Comment: True. However, what I'm finding is that when the site redirects the user at any point, for whatever reason, my filter isn't working :/

Comment: Ahh... this seems to be an issue with the model persisting ... ugh